# Regex to match all occurences of pound(#) within two pipe (|) symbols

Tags: .net, regex

The problem description is;

```
Target String:
##|#|###|##|#|#|||##|##
12345678901234567890123

RegEx: \|\*+\|

Matches:
|#| - 123
|##| - 9012
|#| - 456
|##| - 8901

But **not**
|###| - 56789
|#| - 234
```

Help is appreciated. I am using .NET.
**regex101 link:** https://regex101.com/r/W4jHjv/1

Comment: Because the matches are overlapping. Use capturing group inside a positive lookahead, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/W4jHjv/2).

Comment: You say that `|#| - 123` matches, but `123` doesn't correspond with `|#|` anywhere in your target string.  `(?<=\||^)#+(?=\||$)`